# Mysql SELECT custom fields (post_meta) for custom post type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to query Wordpress posts.

I have created a custom post type `People`.
Each `people` post has custom fields `name`, `age`, `location`, `birthday` and more. The custom fields are created using the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin.

I wand to to query all the custom fields for `People` custom post type.

I want an output like this:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+----------+-----+
| id | post_title  | name          | age    | location                    | birthday   | 
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+----------+-----+
|  1 | SAMPLE      | some_name     | XX     | sample_location             | 10/07/1980 |
|  1 | SAMPLE      | some_name     | XX     | sample_location             | 10/07/1980 |
|  1 | SAMPLE      | some_name     | XX     | sample_location             | 10/07/1980 |
|  1 | SAMPLE      | some_name     | XX     | sample_location             | 10/07/1980 |
|  1 | SAMPLE      | some_name     | XX     | sample_location             | 10/07/1980 |
+----+-------------+-----------+--------+-----------------------------+----------+-----+
```

What would be the proper syntax to do this?

I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_posts` ,  `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE  `post_type` =  'people'
```

But this list all the wordpress regular post fields.

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: You're asking about querying wordpress meta database, you didn't even mention the word "Wordpress" in your question?! be descriptive to find proper answer

Comment: Are you want to display this format on front end side OR just want to proper query for database???

Comment: I use a plugin that will display that in front end. I just need to proper query the database.

Comment: @TanmayPatel can you help with this?

Comment: @Christoforos A can you please share with me link of front end so I can help you.

Comment: @TanmayPatel The plugin that I use output this http://tsite.eu/newmpoffice/editmembers/

This output is based on this code https://codeshare.io/5MnzNO

Comment: @TanmayPatel I have posted the solution below! Thank you for your willingness to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone might have the same question!

```
SELECT posts_people.ID AS people_ID,
   posts_people.post_title AS people_post_title,
   (select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'name' AND post_id = posts_people.ID) as name,
   (select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'age' AND post_id = posts_people.ID) as age,
   (select post_title from wp_posts where ID = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX((select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'location' AND post_id = posts_people.ID),'";',1),':"',-1)) as location,
   (select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = 'birthday' AND post_id = posts_people.ID) as stelexos_kinito
FROM wp_posts AS posts_people
WHERE post_type = 'people' and post_status = 'publish'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're selecting from two tables without joining or setting the relation between them (it should be kind of relationship to join each data set to another)

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM posts as t1 
INNER JOIN postmeta as t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.post_id 
WHERE t1.post_type = 'people' 
AND t2.meta_key = 'name'
```

** NOTE: you should notice your tables names, and replace in query as required, also the columns names in your table.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. So I could use the above code with only changing the post_type and the meta_key?? 
Or do I have to modify it more?

Comment: I left post_type and the meta_key just like yours, try to execute it against your DB

Comment: I get an error MySQL said: Table 'admin_wp24.posts' doesn't exist

Comment: @ChristoforosA - remember, like the note says, you might have tables titled `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`. Remember to change accordingly.